# Two lists in a list of struct in Polars

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I'm really new to Polars.

After running this code

```
fn read_csv() -> Result<(), PolarsError> {
    println!("Hello, polars! ");
    let df = CsvReader::from_path("./test_data/tar-data/csv/unziped/body.csv")?
        .has_header(false)
        .finish()?;

    let df = df.lazy().select([
        col("column_15").str().split("|").alias("origin"),
        col("column_16").str().split("|").alias("destination"),
    ]);
    let mut df = df.collect()?;

    println!("Schema {:?}", df.schema());

    println!("{:?}", df);
    Ok(())
}
```

I have two columns with lists like bellow.
Each column is a List of utf8.

```
Schema Schema:
name: origin, data type: List(Utf8)
name: destination, data type: List(Utf8)

shape: (10, 2)
┌───────────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ origin                ┆ destination           │
│ ---                   ┆ ---                   │
│ list[str]             ┆ list[str]             │
╞═══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ ["JOI", "GRU", "DFW"] ┆ ["VCP", "DFW", "SLC"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["JOI", "GRU", "ATL"] ┆ ["GRU", "ATL", "SLC"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["JOI", "GRU", "MEX"] ┆ ["GRU", "MEX", "SLC"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["JOI", "GRU", "MCO"] ┆ ["GRU", "MCO", "SLC"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                   ┆ ...                   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["JOI", "GRU", "IAH"] ┆ ["VCP", "IAH", "SLC"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["JOI", "GRU", "ORD"] ┆ ["VCP", "ORD", "SLC"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["JOI", "GRU", "JFK"] ┆ ["GRU", "JFK", "SLC"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["JOI", "GRU", "EWR"] ┆ ["GRU", "EWR", "SLC"] │
└───────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Now I need to zip this data info a single column (or Series in Polaris terms) in a form of list of structs.

My goal is to save the DataFrame as JSON with following structure

```
{
    "MyData": [
        [
            {
                "Origin": "JOI",
                "Destination": "VCP"
            },
            {
                "Origin": "GRU",
                "Destination": "DFW"
            },
            {
                "Origin": "DFW",
                "Destination": "SLC"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "Origin": "JOI",
                "Destination": "GRU"
            },
            {
                "Origin": "GRU",
                "Destination": "ATL"
            },
            {
                "Origin": "ATL",
                "Destination": "SLC"
            }
        ],
        ......
    ]
}
```

Which is actually a kind of

```
name: MyData, data type: List(List(Struct([Field { name: "origin", dtype: Utf8 }, Field { name: "destination", dtype: Utf8 }])))
```

I was trying to approach this with apply, fold_exprs, etc, but with no luck.

So, actually my question is **how to create a column with list of predefined structs from N columns with list of data?**

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I think Polars is not the best tool for this job. It makes handling list columns somewhat awkward, especially when you want to include structs in the mix.

Polars's `CsvReader` is useful, and then I think standard Rust can handle this just fine.

data.csv:

```
one,two
JOI|GRU|DFW,VCP|DFW|SLC
JOI|GRU|ATL,GRU|ATL|SLC
```

main.rs:

```
use polars::prelude::*;
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
struct Flight {
    origin: String,
    destination: String,
}

fn read_csv() -> Result<Vec<Vec<Flight>>, PolarsError> {
    let df = CsvReader::from_path("src/data.csv")?
        .has_header(true)
        .finish()?;

    let data = df
        .column("one")?
        .utf8()?
        .into_iter()
        .zip(df.column("two")?.utf8()?)
        .filter_map(|(s1, s2)| {
            let s1 = s1?;
            let s2 = s2?;

            Some(
                s1.split('|')
                    .zip(s2.split('|'))
                    .map(|(src, dst)| Flight {
                        origin: src.into(),
                        destination: dst.into(),
                    })
                    .collect::<Vec<_>>(),
            )
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    Ok(data)
}

fn main() {
    let data = read_csv().expect("problem reading dataframe");
    let out = serde_json::to_string_pretty(&data).expect("problem serializing");
    println!("{}", out);
}
```

Result:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "Origin": "JOI",
      "Destination": "VCP"
    },
    {
      "Origin": "GRU",
      "Destination": "DFW"
    },
    {
      "Origin": "DFW",
      "Destination": "SLC"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Origin": "JOI",
      "Destination": "GRU"
    },
    {
      "Origin": "GRU",
      "Destination": "ATL"
    },
    {
      "Origin": "ATL",
      "Destination": "SLC"
    }
  ]
]
```